# Comparison of the fingerprint sent to the web service with the sample stored in the database

Tags: android, fingerprint

i want save personnel fingerprint to database.( by external fingerprint device ) and in my android application get personnel fingerprint from mobile fingerprint and send it to web service to compare with fingerprint stored in the database  then returned the result of the identity of the person.

I know I can not access to Android device fingerprint for save or send .
Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Comment: mostly the vendors will ship the dedicated sdk to extract fingerprint data which you can use for comparison. one that you can look at is https://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html

Comment: But how do I get fingerprints from mobile without connecting fingerprint device to mobile?

Comment: you need to use specialized scanning hardware that you can connect with device and use sdk to get its data.

Comment: There is no other way?